# Featured product-Drupal commerce

Tags: commerce

I have this issue:I have on a product display a "Featured" checkbox.
I want when this "Featured" checkbox be selected,the price of the product to be increased by some amount when being added to the cart.
So:Normal product will cost 100$ ,if Featured is selected the price will be +50 (150$).
Can this be done with a rule?If so,how?
thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Event:  adding product to the cart.
Conditions:
1. Entity has field (the featured field).
2. Data comparison:  (is that field "on"?)
Action: add amount to the unit price.

I'm not looking directly at the Rules interface, but that should get you well on the correct path.

Comment: Thanks for the answer.Still I cannot make it work.The issue is that the field exists only on the product display,so when I do Data comparison I cannot grab that field.

Comment: You may need to move it to the product entity.  Or within a custom Rules condition, you could run an entity field query for all displays that reference that product.  Provided the product is present on only one display.

Comment: Is there a hook/code so as to inject the product field to the product display?thanks